# Creating a Subfolder in pre-existing folder: SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have been working with SharePoint Designer, and have been creating workflows, but cannot seem to find a way to create a folder inside of another folder that already exists. Now, I have no problem creating a folder and then creating another one inside of it, but I need to be able to add the subfolder to a pre-existing folder. Can anyone help. I am using SharePoint Designer 2010. I keep getting the error that it could not create the list item and to make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to the list. I am the owner with all permissions and the list does exist. I can give you more details if you have specific questions. I have tried referencing the data several different ways, starting with the way in which I referenced it to create a folder and subfolder, but am having no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the existing folder name? See this blog post for details: http://www.getinthesky.com/2012/08/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/

It involves creating the folder and subfolder in the same workflow, however, the parent folder must be created first anyway.